# CASE WHEN THEN Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql

this is my code:

```
SELECT SUM 
        (CASE
            WHEN (dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbEst) = 0 THEN

                0
            WHEN (dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbEst) = 3 THEN 
                0
            WHEN (dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbEst) = 6 THEN 
                0       
            WHEN (dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbEst) = 7 THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT COUNT (dbo.CUMPLIDO.CumpCod) from dbo.CUMPLIDO where dbo.CUMPLIDO.EmbCod = dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbCod and dbo.CUMPLIDO.CumpVol = 0) > 0 THEN 
                        0
                    ELSE  
                        dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbVol
                END
            ELSE
                dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbVol
        END) FROM dbo.EMBARQUE
```

Comment: Please inform us what DBMS you're using

Comment: Could you explain more detail on your question?

Comment: What error do you get and Is `dbo.EMBARQUE.EmbVol` numeric ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867088/sql-server-cannot-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-a) You have a subquery in your CASE statement and therefore you can't aggregate on the results of that CASE statement within the same SELECT statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a subquery inside `sum()`.  That isn't allowed.  This version uses a subquery to calculate the flag you want and then moves the filtering logic to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(e.EmbVol)
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CUMPLIDO c WHERE c.EmbCod = e.EmbCod AND c.CumpVol = 0)
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0
              END) as is_CumpVol_0
      FROM dbo.EMBARQUE e
      WHERE e.EmbEst NOT IN (0, 3, 6)
     ) e
WHERE e.EmbEst <> 7 OR is_CumpVol_0 = 0;
```